# JAVA SAX Parsing Error

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax, xml-parsing

so I been asking a couple questions here today and with the help of the amazing SO community I've been able to understand the basics of SAX, as well as learn how to properly traverse a directory structure.

Now, with my program, I can access the XML file I am looking for, but I am not sure what this error I am getting means or where I am going wrong within the code for my SAXHandler class. Could someone take a look at this and give me some feedback?

**XML FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
      <Relationship Id="rId8" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/footer" Target="footer1.xml" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId13" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/theme" Target="theme/theme1.xml" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId3" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/settings" Target="settings.xml" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId7" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/header" Target="header1.xml" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId12" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/fontTable" Target="fontTable.xml" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/styles" Target="styles.xml" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/numbering" Target="numbering.xml" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId6" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/endnotes" Target="endnotes.xml" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId11" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image" Target="media/image3.png" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId5" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/footnotes" Target="footnotes.xml" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId10" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image" Target="media/image2.jpeg" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId4" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/webSettings" Target="webSettings.xml" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId9" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image" Target="media/image1.jpeg" /> 
</Relationships>
```

**Java Code**

```
import java.io.*;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.*;

public class XMLParser
{   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        traverse(new File("C:/Documents and Settings/user/workspace/Intern Project/Proposals/Converted Proposals/Extracted Items"));
    }

     private static final class SaxHandler extends DefaultHandler 
     {
         // invoked when document-parsing is started:
         public void startDocument() throws SAXException 
         {
             System.out.println("Document processing started");
         }

         // notifies about finish of parsing:
         public void endDocument() throws SAXException 
         {
             System.out.println("Document processing finished");
         }

         // we enter to element 'qName':
         public void startElement(String uri, String localName, 
                 String qName, Attributes attrs) throws SAXException 
         {
             if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Relationship"))
         {
             String val = attrs.getValue("Target");
             if(val != null)
             {
                 if (val.contains("image"))
                 {
                     String id = attrs.getValue("Id");
                     System.out.println("Id: " + id + "& Target: " + val);
                 }
             }
         }
         else if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Relationships"))
         {
             //do nothing
         }
         else 
         {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Element '" + 
                     qName + "' is not allowed here");
         }
         }

         // we leave element 'qName' without any actions:
         public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
         throws SAXException 
         {
                // do nothing;
         }
     }

     private static void traverse(File directory)
     {
        //Get all files in directory
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : files)
        {
           if (file.isDirectory())
           {
              //It's a directory so (recursively) traverse it
              traverse(file);
           }
           else if (file.getName().equals("document.xml.rels"))
           {
               try 
                {
                    System.out.println("5");
                    // creates and returns new instance of SAX-implementation:
                    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

                    // create SAX-parser...
                    SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

                    // .. define our handler:
                    SaxHandler handler = new SaxHandler();

                    // and parse:
                    parser.parse(file.getAbsolutePath(), handler);    
                } 
                catch (Exception ex) 
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
                }
            }
         }
     }
}
```

**Error**

```
5
Document processing started
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Element 'Relationships' is not allowed here
    at XMLParser$SaxHandler.startElement(XMLParser.java:57)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at XMLParser.traverse(XMLParser.java:96)
    at XMLParser.traverse(XMLParser.java:79)
    at XMLParser.traverse(XMLParser.java:79)
    at XMLParser.traverse(XMLParser.java:79)
    at XMLParser.main(XMLParser.java:13)
5
Document processing started
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Element 'Relationships' is not allowed here
    at XMLParser$SaxHandler.startElement(XMLParser.java:57)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at XMLParser.traverse(XMLParser.java:96)
    at XMLParser.traverse(XMLParser.java:79)
    at XMLParser.traverse(XMLParser.java:79)
    at XMLParser.traverse(XMLParser.java:79)
    at XMLParser.main(XMLParser.java:13)
5
Document processing started
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Element 'Relationships' is not allowed here
    at XMLParser$SaxHandler.startElement(XMLParser.java:57)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at XMLParser.traverse(XMLParser.java:96)
    at XMLParser.traverse(XMLParser.java:79)
    at XMLParser.traverse(XMLParser.java:79)
    at XMLParser.traverse(XMLParser.java:79)
    at XMLParser.main(XMLParser.java:13)
5
Document processing started
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Element 'Relationships' is not allowed here
    at XMLParser$SaxHandler.startElement(XMLParser.java:57)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at XMLParser.traverse(XMLParser.java:96)
    at XMLParser.traverse(XMLParser.java:79)
    at XMLParser.traverse(XMLParser.java:79)
    at XMLParser.traverse(XMLParser.java:79)
    at XMLParser.main(XMLParser.java:13)
```

**Working Output Thanks to Jorge M.**

```
Document processing started
Id: rId13& Target: media/image3.jpeg
Id: rId18& Target: media/image8.jpeg
Id: rId26& Target: media/image16.jpeg
Id: rId39& Target: media/image29.jpeg
Id: rId21& Target: media/image11.jpeg
Id: rId34& Target: media/image24.jpeg
Id: rId7& Target: media/image1.jpeg
Id: rId12& Target: media/image2.jpeg
Id: rId17& Target: media/image7.jpeg
Id: rId25& Target: media/image15.jpeg
Id: rId33& Target: media/image23.jpeg
Id: rId38& Target: media/image28.jpeg
Id: rId16& Target: media/image6.jpeg
Id: rId20& Target: media/image10.jpeg
Id: rId29& Target: media/image19.jpeg
Id: rId24& Target: media/image14.jpeg
Id: rId32& Target: media/image22.jpeg
Id: rId37& Target: media/image27.jpeg
Id: rId15& Target: media/image5.jpeg
Id: rId23& Target: media/image13.jpeg
Id: rId28& Target: media/image18.jpeg
Id: rId36& Target: media/image26.jpeg
Id: rId19& Target: media/image9.jpeg
Id: rId31& Target: media/image21.jpeg
Id: rId14& Target: media/image4.jpeg
Id: rId22& Target: media/image12.jpeg
Id: rId27& Target: media/image17.jpeg
Id: rId30& Target: media/image20.jpeg
Id: rId35& Target: media/image25.jpeg
Document processing finished
Document processing started
Id: rId11& Target: media/image2.png
Id: rId9& Target: media/image1.jpeg
Document processing finished
Document processing started
Id: rId11& Target: media/image3.png
Id: rId10& Target: media/image2.jpeg
Id: rId9& Target: media/image1.jpeg
Document processing finished
Document processing started
Id: rId8& Target: media/image2.jpeg
Id: rId13& Target: media/image5.jpeg
Id: rId7& Target: media/image1.jpeg
Id: rId12& Target: media/image4.jpeg
Id: rId17& Target: media/image8.png
Id: rId15& Target: media/image7.jpeg
Id: rId9& Target: media/image3.jpeg
Id: rId14& Target: media/image6.jpeg
Document processing finished
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: What does your XML look like? Off-hand, I'd guess that you have two top-level elements.

Comment: There may be nothing wrong with your code. The problem seems to be with the source documentation. The document does not seem to be compliant with the schema. Just remove the dtd definition and try reading the file using sax and it should work ( to verify my assumption)

Comment: @Ted Hopp, @doc_180 Sorry about that, I forgot to include the xml document the first time. It's in the original post now.

Comment: @Joe - is that `-` before the opening `<Relationships ...` tag actually in the xml file?

Comment: @Joe then remove it because it does not belong there, it makes it an invalid XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every start element you check if its equal to "Relationship" but the first Element is "Relationships" so its not equal and you throw an exception. Thats the behavior you implemented so far ;)

Thats the peace of code im referencing to:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, 
                 String qName, Attributes attrs) throws SAXException 
         {
             if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Relationship"))
             {
                 .....
             }  
             else 
             {
                 throw new IllegalArgumentException("Element '" + 
                         qName + "' is not allowed here");
             }
         }
```

A possible solution(It is definitely not good style but solves the problem which you face)

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, 
                 String qName, Attributes attrs) throws SAXException 
         {
             if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Relationship"))
             {
                 .....
             }
             else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Relationships") {
                  // do nothing
             }
             else 
             {
                 throw new IllegalArgumentException("Element '" + 
                         qName + "' is not allowed here");
             }
         }
```

Comment: @Joerg M. Hmm yeah, I see where the error is coming in from now. But does that mean the localName is not 'Relationship'? And if that's the case, what should I start at to access 'Relationships'?

Comment: look this method is a callback handler. And this callback handler is fired on every opening tag in the xml ... but the root element in this example "relationships" is also an opening tag. You could easily solve the problem with an elseif handling the case where localName equals "Relationships"

Comment: @Joerg M. Well I followed your advice and I included a new else-if statement to handle the 'Relationships' tag. However, I am still getting the same error. I included the change I made in my original code.

Comment: @Joerg M. Just made a slight modiciation to my code. I did as you said including the else-if statement, however, as opposed to using LocalName, I used qName...and surprisingly, it worked. Now...I have no idea why this is the case as from the explanations I had received, people told me they were basically the same thing. Do you understand this? *Edit: changes reflected in the code*

Comment: Take my example and replace localName with qName. You will not get an error. I correct the example, one moment.

Comment: lol just beat you to it haha, thanks a lot man, very much appreciate it!